# Visual Basic 2010 Express - How to use excel function in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net

I want to use excel function in Visual Basic 2010 Express. I tried to search in the internet to see how to do that.

I come across with this solution:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

        Dim oXLApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim ExcelMath As Excel.WorksheetFunction
        ExcelMath = New Excel.WorksheetFunction

        Dim I As Double
        Dim s As Double

        I = ExcelMath.Average(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        s = ExcelMath.StDev(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        ExcelMath = Nothing
        oXLApp.Quit()
        oXLApp = Nothing

    End Sub

End Module
```

However, there is error of:
1. Syntax error.
2. Type 'Excel.Applciation" is not defined.
3. Type 'Excel.WorksheetFunction' is not defined.

How should it be resolved?

Or is there other simple way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to add a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library. For a brief tutorial, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982 (more specifically, step #3).

If this doesn't resolve the problem, let us know.

Comment: Thank you. Though when I try to run the codes, it says MissingMemberException was unhandled, then says "Public member 'WorksheetFucntion' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found", how to resolve this?

Comment: It has been resolved, here it is:
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim oXLApp As New Excel.Application


        Dim I As Double
        Dim s As Double

        I = oXLApp.WorksheetFunction.Average(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        s = oXLApp.WorksheetFunction.StDev(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

        oXLApp.Quit()
        oXLApp = Nothing


    End Sub

End Module

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it has to do with using the Express edition or not, but I had the same problem.

Whenever I attempted to use `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` it would not work.

I went to Project > Add References > COM > `Microsoft Office14.0 Object Library` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Include an import statement at the top : `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`